# TYPO3 Routing: List & Details Action on same Page

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

When accessing the details page an exception is thrown: `The action "details" (controller "Products") is not allowed by this plugin.`

My **Route Enhancer** looks like this:

```
ProductsPlugin:
  type:              Extbase
  extension:         Myext
  plugin:            Products
  routes:
    -
      routePath:   '/{product_slug}'
      _controller: 'Products::details'
      _arguments:
        product_slug: productId
  defaultController: 'Products::list'
  defaults:
    productId: '0'
  aspects:
    product_slug:
      type: ProductsValueMapper
```

The **Plugin** is embedded via **TypoScript**:

```
lib.productsContent = USER
lib.productsContent {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Myext
    pluginName = Products
    vendorName = Vendor

    switchableControllerActions {
        Products {
            1 = list
        }
    }
}

[request.getQueryParams()['tx_myext_products']['productId'] > 0]
    lib.productsContent.switchableControllerActions.Products.1 = details
[end]
```

The links in the **Fluid-Template** are generated by:

```
<f:link.action class="button more" pageUid="38" action="details" arguments="{productId: '{product.product.id}'}">Mehr</f:link.action>
```

I tried switching between list & details for `_controller` and `defaultController`. I also tried removing one or both, but either the generated links contain the GET-Params or the Detailview creates the error message above.

Can anyone push me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
When I remove `_controller: 'Products::details'` the error message is gone and my details action is called properly. But then the links to the details action contain the regular GET-params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the plugin was embedded multiple times on the same page, which causes problems.

To solve this you can either create different plugins or set `plugin.tx_myext_products.mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1`

See: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1313855175

Comment: I am using multiple instances of the same plugin on the same page like you and I also have set "callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1", but I am still not able to generate correct URLs. I don't include the plugins via typoscript, but via plugin content elements and flexform switchable controller actions. If I remove the "_controller" section in my route enhancer then the correct URL like (/product/example) is still visitable, but URL generation on other sites via f:link.action or f:link.typolink will not work as you described above. So default actions will not work for me :(.

Answer (score 1):

can you please check this patch? https://review.typo3.org/c/59343/ Two people, including me, had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the patch. But unfortunately the result is still the same. I also updated my post.